# hiding multiple fields in html form

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple fields with same id in HTML form and I want to hide them if the value of a particular field is 1 but it only hides the first field of that id all other fields are not hidden

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input" id="g">Days of week</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="checkbok">
            <label for="example-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g" name="gender" value="monday">Monday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbok">
            <label for="example-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g" name="gender" value="tuesday">Tuesday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbok">
            <label for="example-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g" name="gender" value="wednesday">Wednesday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbok">
            <label for="example-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g" name="gender" value="thursday">Thursday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbok">
            <label for="example-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g" name="gender" value="friday">Friday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbok">
            <label for="example-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g" name="gender" value="saturday">Saturday
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbok">
            <label for="example-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="g" name="gender" value="sunday"> Sunday
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input" id="g">Time</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select id="g" name="nod" class="form-control">
        <?php 
            for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
                echo"<option value='$i'>$i AM</option>"; 
            } 
            for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
                echo "<option value='12+$i'>$i PM</option>";
            }?>                         
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

All the elements have the same id="g".Below is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ele=document.getElementById("st").value;
    if(ele==1)
        document.getElementById("g").style.visibility = "hidden";
    //else
        //document.getElementById("g").style.visibility = "none";
</script>
```

But only the first element(ie the text days of week) gets hidden all others are shown.How do I hide all the others

Comment: *All the elements have the same id="g"* — Start by fixing that. HTML does not allow it. http://validator.w3.org/nu/ may be helpful.

Comment: check this page should have only one element with specific ID they should not repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types

Comment: Agreed. An HTML document cannot have more than a single element with the same ID. That is why Javascript is only finding the first element, then stopping. Use classes and `getElementsByClassName` instead.

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique in html fields,but you can have same name attribute/classname. you have to loop through the array of elements extracted using classname or name attribute.

**in your case  use name attribute**

```
 function hideGender(){
     var ele=document.getElementById("st").value;
   if(ele==1){
    var elements=document.getElementsByName("gender");
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
     elements[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
   }
 }
```

Comment: `elements[i]..style.visibility = "hidden";` needs fixing to 1 dot

Answer (score -1):

IDs should be unique within the document.
Change `id="g"` to `class="g"`.

```
 <label for="example-checkbox1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="g" name="gender" value="saturday"> Saturday
 </label>


    <script type="text/javascript">
   Array.filter( 
   document.getElementsByClassName('g'),
   function(elem){
   elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

To select multiple fields with same id you will have to use -

```
$('[id="yourFieldId"]');
```

So in your case -

```
var ele=document.getElementById("st").value;
if(ele==1)
   $('[id="yourFieldId"]').hide();
```

Comment: what? this will not work. and very bad practice whole point of a ID is to be unique simply use a class instead thats the whole point of classes

Comment: I agree that this is bad practice, but the jquery will work, though the original question doesn't mention jquery

Comment: @Josh Stevens I have already tried that, and it works. Your point is absolutely correct, one should use a class to select multiple fields. But his requirement was with id, so the solution fits.